# get gps location from mobile phone

Tags: jquery, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I would like to know What is the best way to get the gps locations off multiple phones on to a googlemaps on a website. I just downloaded googlemaps with latitude on my phone. 
Is it only possible to query your own location with the public location badge, or can you also get the locations off your "friends". Anyone got experience with this?

**If it's - not yet - possible to get multiple phone locations, what would be the alternative?** I have to say that it must be gps based and not based on cellid because that one is to inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Latitude for it: http://www.google.be/latitude/

To make your own thing with the Google API, you can lookup your position on your iPhone in Safari with a special API: http://blog.bemoko.com/2009/06/17/iphone-30-geolocation-javascript-api/

Comment: Thanks, but I need the locations off multiple phones. I don't have an iphone, but even if I had then I can not see a solution in the link you provided. It has to be accessible from a website! I am back on my laptop and not on my phone, a nokia 5800, so I can read a little better. I made the question a little more clear.

Comment: apperantly, you can get a feed, there are some drawbacks, mainly because googlemaps does not work in the background in most phones.
I have too investigate some more.